# Insert a Node at a Specific Position in a Linked List

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I need to insert a note at position. I didn't get any error but my answer is wrong. Could you please help me to correct my code?
 [Link to question](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/insert-a-node-at-a-specific-position-in-a-linked-list/problem)

```
Node InsertNth(Node head, int data, int position) {
    Node node = new Node();
    node.data = data;
 if (head == null){
        return node;
    } else {
    Node current = head;
    for (int i=0; i < position-1 ; i++){
        current = current.next;
    }

    node.next = current.next;
    current.next = node;
 return head;
}

}
```

Comment: Show the `input`, `output` of the program and expected `output`

Comment: input (stdin)
5
3 0
5 1
4 2
2 3
1 0

output
210542

expected output
310542

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a dummy node that points to the head can help reduce many of the check:

```
Node insertNth(Node head, int data, int position) {
    Node dummy = new Node();
    dummy.next = head;

    Node runner = dummy;
    for (int i = 0; i < position; ++i) {
        runner = runner.next;
    }

    Node node = new Node();
    node.data = data;
    node.next = runner.next;
    runner.next = node;

    return dummy.next;
}
```

Naturally, a recursive solution is also possible:

```
Node insertNthRecursive(Node head, int data, int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        Node node = new Node();
        node.data = data;
        node.next = head;
        return node;
    }
    head.next = insertNthRecursive(head.next, data, position - 1);
    return head;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Node insertAt(Node head, int data, int position) {
    Node node = new Node();
    node.data = data;
    if (position == 0) {
        node.next = head;
        return node;
    } else {
        head.next = insertAt(head.next, data, position - 1);
        return head;
    }
    /* Or iterative
    Node current = head;
    Node previous = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < position && current != null; i++) {
        previous = current;
        current = current.next;
    }
    node.next = current;
    if (previous == null) {
        head = node;
    } else {
        previous.next = node;
    }
    return head;
    */
}
```

This does not do an IndexOutOfBoundsException.